# Создание таблицы sqlite3 python

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

Пишу проект на питоне в VSCode. Создал отдельную папку, где лежит сам проект: основной файл питон; файл по работе с таблицой, при помощи sqlite3. Когда работаю с таблицой, она создается не в этой папке, из-за чего начинается конфликт файлов. Если переместить её обратно в папку, при повторной работе, создается новая таблица, опять не в этой папке. Как сделать так, чтобы питон или VSCode могли создавать файл в специально отведенной папке.

Пытался реализовать так:

```
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS name (

)""")
```

Comment: В строке соединения укажите путь к БД: `'/folder/file.db'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with sqlite3.connect('C:\\Users\\2007a\\OneDrive\\Documents\\Pythonproject\\telegram_bot\\telebot_database.db') as db:
    c = db.cursor()
```

Нужно указать в sqlite3.connect() путь, где создать файл